# Creating a single CW post for the Windows 8.1 0xc1900101/Upgrade Bootup issue

Tags: discussion, canonical-answer

There are quite a few questions out there regarding upgrading to Windows 8.1 and then running into a BSOD and then subsequent reversion back to Windows 8:

1. [Windows 8.1 couldn't be installed with error 0xc1900101 0x20006](https://superuser.com/questions/661465/windows-8-1-couldnt-be-installed-with-error-0xc1900101-0x20006)
2. [Windows 8.1 upgrade fail with error 0xC1900101](https://superuser.com/questions/662163/windows-8-1-upgrade-fail-with-error-0xc1900101)
3. [windows 8.1 upgrade from win 8 fails with error code 0xc1900101-0x20017](https://superuser.com/questions/668521/windows-8-1-upgrade-from-win-8-fails-with-error-code-0xc1900101-0x20017)
4. [windows 8.1 upgrade fails with error code 0xc1900101-0x20017](https://superuser.com/questions/661311/windows-8-1-upgrade-fails-with-error-code-0xc1900101-0x20017)
5. [Windows 8.1 will not boot after upgrading from Windows 8 on my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/665438/windows-8-1-will-not-boot-after-upgrading-from-windows-8-on-my-pc)
6. [BSOD after installing old driver in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/694161/bsod-after-installing-old-driver-in-windows-8-1)

I'm sure there are probably others out there that I haven't found.  I would like to create   single question that would be similar to what we've done with other common questions where we post the question and a community wiki answer.  We would then close these questions as a duplicate of the new one.  This would preserve any reputation earned from the older posts, while giving a more succinct and clean solution to a common problem at hand.  What does the community think?

Comment: I'm ok with the general idea, but why Community wiki?

Comment: I don't want other to think that I'm trying to rep whore off of a common issue.

Comment: I was reading most of the questions but apparently each solution is very very specific to each one situation. I think that you have better chances asking "How to discover the causes of 0xc1900101 error code?" instead. Is not a "how to fix", but "how to know what's wrong" which is more helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq)

This is what it's there for! Go do it!

Comment: I'll put this together later tonight.  Will reply with the result.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the idea.

Making a single community-wiki post for this problem would ensure that the question's answer is in one place, which is one of the goals of Stack Exchange. Additionally, if you have six different questions with the same purpose, but no one of them is canonical, it would be a good idea to make a new canonical post in order to ensure that the specifics in those six are preserved. I envision having multiple answers to that question for most of the various causes of the problem, and if one of them is not covered in them, one could post a new question with the specifics, have it answered, have it closed as a duplicate of the canonical one, and then the poster of the question can add another answer with his specifics and his solution to the canonical question. The question should also be protected to safeguard against the possibility of a new user asking his specific question as an answer, which wouldn't be an answer.